# security concerns on sharepoint deployment

Tags: 2010, security

I've inherited our company's SP 2010 deployment. I'm looking for security flaws and other potential issues. Any suggestions as to what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TechNet article for security hardening is pretty good:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262849(v=office.14).aspx

You definitely want to make sure that the service accounts are setup properly.  Here is the guideance on service accounts:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445(v=office.14).aspx

If the system is setup for access by external users, I also make sure that the service applications are isolated for content that is internal only versus shared with external users.